# Explode php array and store variable value to DB

Tags: php, mysql

Transaction initiated for payment and Got the revert form a transaction and want to display result on page ans save to my DB

```
    if (!($data = curl_exec($ch))) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
    print "\n$data\n";
    $data = explode("&",$data);
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
        $rdata = explode("=",$data[$i]);
        $this->responses[$rdata[0]] = $rdata[1];
    }
    return $this->responses['response'];
  }

Result
response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=2766128623&avsresponse=N&cvvresponse=M&orderid=1123400&type=sale&response_code=100
```

now i want to display each items on page like
Responce = 1
Responce Text = Success

Comment: I am not sure but `json` might help you

Answer (score 1):

it is called query string. You can do

```
parse_str ('response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=2766128623&avsresponse=N&cvvresponse=M&orderid=1123400&type=sale&response_code=100', $resp);
print_r($resp);
```

and give the result array

```
Array
(
    [response] => 1
    [responsetext] => SUCCESS
    [authcode] => 123456
    [transactionid] => 2766128623
    [avsresponse] => N
    [cvvresponse] => M
    [orderid] => 1123400
    [type] => sale
    [response_code] => 100
)
```

Or don't say the 2nd argument, and then you will give variables with names as array keys

Answer (score 1):

Do it normally as follows -

```
$data = "response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=2766128623&avsresponse=N&cvvresponse=M&orderid=1123400&type=sale&response_code=100";

$data = explode("&",$data);


// use print_r if needed
//print_r($data);

foreach($data as $d) {
  echo $d .'<br/>';
}
```

And For Key/ Label you have to do some `pregmatch` trick to achieve something like -

`Response Text or Response or Auth Code`

Comment: getting error message Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: I have tested the code @ [WriteCodeOnline](http://www.writephponline.com). It's working

Comment: but i am getting this on display on page 

response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=2766128623&avsresponse=N&cvvresponse=M&orderid=1123400&type=sale&response_code=100

so how can i add this into variable, thanks for the support i have just started writing code so sorry to bother you for silly mistake if any

Answer (score 0):

you can try `str_replace()` for replacing '&' with ' ', and you can use `ucwords()` for capitalization

like this

`ucwords(str_replace('&',$this->responses['response'];))`